# Text processing tool for tweets

Tags: nlp, entity, text-processing, sentiment-analysis, named-entity-recognition

I am collecting millions of sports related tweets daily. I want to process the text in those tweets. I want to recognize the entities, find the sentiment of the sentence and find the events in those tweets.

Entity recognizing :

For example :
"Rooney will play for England in their next match".

From this tweet i want to recognize person entity "Rooney" and place entity "England"

sentiment analysis:

I want to find the sentiment of a sentence. For example

1. Chelsea played their worst game ever
2. Ronaldo scored a beautiful goal

The first one should marked as "negative" sentence and the later one should marked as "positive".

Event recognizing :

I want to find "goal scoring event" from tweets. Sentences like  "messi scored goal in first half" and "that was a fantastic goal from gerrald" should marked as "goal scoring event".

I know entity recognizing and sentiment analysis tools are available and i need to write the rules for event recognizing. I have seen so many tools like `Stanford NER`, `alchemy api`, `open calais`, `meaning cloud api`, `ling pipe`, `illinois` etc..
I'm really confused about which tool I should select? Is there any free tools available without daily rate limits? I want to process millions of tweets daily and `java` is my preferable language.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Given the consideration that your preferred language is Java, I would strongly suggest to start with Stanford NLP project. Most of your basic needs like cleansing, chunking, NER can be done based on that. [For NER click here.](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml)

Going ahead for sentiment analysis you can use simplistic classifiers like Naive Bayes and then add complexities. More [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/naive-bayes-text-classification-1.html).

For the event extraction, you can use linguistic approach to identify the verbs with their association with ontology on your side.

Just remember, this is just to get you started and no way an extensive answer.

Comment: Is it possible to find the meta information of an entity using stanford NER? It is available in alchemy. Example Lionel messi-FootballPlayer. Alchemy also give dbPedia url of the entity.

Comment: No. It doesn't. If you are looking to build something quickly and deliver, Alchemy makes a lot more sense. If you want to build something that gets better with time and is highly configurable then Stanford will make more sense. Depends on your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

For NER you can also use [TwitIE](https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/twitie.html) which is a GATE pipeline so you can use it using the GATE API in Java.

Answer (score 1):

No API with unlimited call availalble. IF you want to stick with java, use stanford package with customization as per your need.

If you are comfortable with python, look at `nltk`.

Well, for `person`, `organization` stanford will work, for your input query :

```
Rooney will play for England in their next match
[Text=Rooney CharacterOffsetBegin=0 CharacterOffsetEnd=6 PartOfSpeech=NNP Lemma=Rooney NamedEntityTag=PERSON] [Text=will CharacterOffsetBegin=7 CharacterOffsetEnd=11 PartOfSpeech=MD Lemma=will NamedEntityTag=O] [Text=play CharacterOffsetBegin=12 CharacterOffsetEnd=16 PartOfSpeech=VB Lemma=play NamedEntityTag=O] [Text=for CharacterOffsetBegin=17 CharacterOffsetEnd=20 PartOfSpeech=IN Lemma=for NamedEntityTag=O] [Text=England CharacterOffsetBegin=21 CharacterOffsetEnd=28 PartOfSpeech=NNP Lemma=England NamedEntityTag=LOCATION] [Text=in CharacterOffsetBegin=29 CharacterOffsetEnd=31 PartOfSpeech=IN Lemma=in NamedEntityTag=O] [Text=their CharacterOffsetBegin=32 CharacterOffsetEnd=37 PartOfSpeech=PRP$ Lemma=they NamedEntityTag=O] [Text=next CharacterOffsetBegin=38 CharacterOffsetEnd=42 PartOfSpeech=JJ Lemma=next NamedEntityTag=O] [Text=match CharacterOffsetBegin=43 CharacterOffsetEnd=48 PartOfSpeech=NN Lemma=match NamedEntityTag=O]
```

If you want to add `event`recognization too, you need to retrain the stanford package with extrac class having `event` based dataset. Which can help you to classify event based input.

> Does the NER use part-of-speech tags?
>
> None of our current models use pos tags by default. This is largely
>   because the features used by the Stanford POS tagger are very similar
>   to those used in the NER system, so there is very little benefit to
>   using POS tags.
>
> However, it certainly is possible to train new models which do use POS
>   tags. The training data would need to have an extra column with the
>   tag information, and you would then add tag=X to the map parameter.

check - http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml

Comment: Is it possible to find the meta information of an entity using stanford NER? It is available in alchemy. Example Lionel messi-FootballPlayer. Alchemy also give dbPedia url of the entity.

Comment: @DinoopNair: StanfordNER is not that much intelligent, alchemyAPI is paid. To get this sort of result you have to train your data with relevant data. Or you can create your own NER tagger with indexing and classification

Answer (score 1):

Stanford NER and OPENNLP are both open-source and have models that perform well on formal article/texts. 
But their accuracy drops significantly over Twitter (from 90% recall over formal text to 40% recall over tweets)
The informal nature of tweets (bad capitalization, spellings, punctuations), improper usage of words, vernacularity and emoticons  makes it more complicated
NER, sentiment analysis and event extraction over tweets is a well-researched area apparently for its applications.

Take a look at this: https://github.com/aritter/twitter_nlp, see this demo of twitter NLP and event extraction: http://ec2-54-170-89-29.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/

Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to find the meta information of an entity using stanford NER? It is available in alchemy. Example Lionel messi-FootballPlayer. Alchemy also give dbPedia url of the entity.

Comment: I am pretty sure, Alchemy does it by just direct DBpedia match and retrieves the type of the entity. These NER libraries may not readily be doing that, but it should be very easy to add.